# How do I grab recent searches?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I do have a personal web search engine by `PHP` and a `MySQL` database. I want to grab the recent searches done by users and display the same. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by "display the same" ?

Comment: display recent searches to search page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new table and you can log the user's ip, search, time stamp, etc.

Or if you don't want to do that, you can create a text file and have it log to it... Just make sure it's something unique so no one can look at it!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to store their searches in a table.